# handle escape (@) character in xamarin xaml

Tags: c#, regex, xamarin.forms

I have a `RegExText` bindable property in custom `Entry` control on `Xamarin.Forms`, I suppose to give ExpressionText in `RegExText` property. When I tried to validate email address. It is showing nested qualifier exception.

```
<local:CustomRegexEntry x:Name="entryEmail" 
                        Placeholder="{Binding .EmailLabelText}" 
                        FontAttributes="Italic" 
                        Text="{Binding EmailID}"
                        Image="Email"
                        RegExText="^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$"
                        Unfocused="onEntryEmail_Unfocused"/>
```

How can I include @ character on `RegExText` property.

Comment: Try `RegExText="^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)[.]([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$"`

Comment: tried but its not valid email expression. I didn't get any error this time.

Comment: What do you mean to say by *its not valid email expression*? That means your regex is not a valid email regex, right? Then why are you using it at all?

Comment: Yes, I have changed to new valid email expression. Now working fine. My main intention is how to handle nested quantifier error on such scenarios like inputting regular expression in XAML through bindable property.

Comment: You had no real issue, just the `-` created an invalid range I guess.